# Two Heroku apps w/ domain and subdomain in Godaddy for Mailgun verification

Tags: heroku, dns, mailgun

I can't find anything about this particular issue after searching a while so I'm at the point where I think I might be going about it the wrong way.  My understanding of DNS is not great so I might just be missing something obvious.

Say I have a domain `tomato.com` and I have two Heroku apps, one staging and one production, and I've added the Mailgun add-on to both of them.  In the Heroku CLI, I added `tomato.com` as a domain to my production app (Heroku defaults to `ALIAS or ANAME`), and `staging.tomato.com` to my staging app (Heroku defaults to `CNAME`).  In Godaddy, I've added a `CNAME` DNS entry with the name `staging` and the "data" the DNS Target provided by Heroku.  All of these seem to be working correctly in the browser.

In Godaddy, I was able to add `TXT` DNS entires for `SPF` and `DKIM` with the values provided by the Mailgun addon in my production app for `tomato.com`, but when I try to add a `TXT` entry with the name `staging` and the data `v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all`, I get an error: `Record name staging conflicts with another record`, I'm assuming due to the `CNAME` record I added for `staging` in order to get that subdomain to redirect to the staging heroku app.

How can I add the Mailgun DNS entries required for verification of my staging app if I can only make one entry of any type that uses the `staging` name?

Comment: You can't have any other records alongside a CNAME. You'll need to do an ALIAS/ANAME style approach for the subdomain just like the main domain.

Comment: @ceejayoz I had tried setting up an A record but Godaddy isn't accepting either the DNS Target supplied by heroku or the app URL, ex. tomat-staging.herokuapp.com when I try to create an A type record.